# Find d this ones stumped me help?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

[image]

This one is annoying me so much. Got this from a maths teacher.

Answer (score 31):

D is equal to:

> 9

Explanation:

> Each number written as a word has a roman numeral hidden inside. Nine has 'I', which is 1. Seven has 'V', which is 5. Five has 'IV', which is 4. Therefore, we look at Six and in it is hidden 'IX', which is 9.